# Can I install Windows on an iMac, and will that Windows have full functionality as a normal PC

Tags: windows, boot-camp, imac, asp.net

I'm intending to buy a new iMAC for iOS programming and graphics processing. But I also work on ASP.NET and PHP. I've thought about installing a VM that runs Windows 7 but it would be painfully slow. My friends said that I can install Windows on OSX with BootCamp. I would like to ask if the Windows installed with BootCamp has full functionalities as a normal Windows on a PC.

Answer (score 4):

This is can easily be done by using Bootcamp assistant, check manuals here http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/. But its probably you can install windows without reading manual. The assistant steps are very clear. And yes, windows will work with full functionality as if it was installed on PC

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does have full functionality.
After all, a `Mac` is a computer, too. There are no problems, because `Apple` provides all the necessary Windows-drivers for the hardware, so that Windows will function properly. You can operate it just like a "normal" PC with Windows.
See [here](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) for the official support for `BootCamp` on Apple-Computers.